# Taking a break between master’s and PhD in Physics

Tags: phd, masters, united-states, united-kingdom

To any PhD holders or candidates out there, how common is it to take a break after your master’s before applying for a PhD course? I currently have my master’s and due to bond fulfillment have a research attachment for a few years.

Would my PhD candidacy be any more difficult/less viable because I’m both older and have been away from academia longer than those who have gone directly from an MSc to a PhD course?

Comment: What country are you in?  Customs often vary by country.

Comment: @jakebeal I'm in Australia, but I would like to know the customs for the US and UK too since I've done my undergrad studies in the UK and am intending to go to one of those countries for a PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Many people find it more difficult to pass their PhD exams if they take a significant break.  It can often be helpful to have things fresh in one's mind for the exams.  However, this, of course, can vary by the individual.

Comment: Good answer for the US, but I think there are no exams in the UK.